# Create PDF with DOMPDF and Redirect

Tags: php, dompdf

In a PHP project I need to Create a PDF file and redirect to another page when user clicks a Submit button.
I have managed to create the pdf file using [DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/). PDF creation is done in a seperate file `('PDFRecipt.php')`.
I have called that page when a user clicks a button on the main page. This is how  call PDF page

```
header('location:PDFRecipt.php');
```

but the problem is when I try  to redirect after calling PDF page by

```
header('location:Other.php');
```

It does not create the PDF (only redirects). I tried changing 
`header('location:PDFRecipt.php');`
to 
`include_once('PDFRecipt.php');`

then it does not create the PDF correctly (Corrupted PDF File)

How to create the PDF file & redirect to other page?

**EDIT:**

Code in `PDFRecipt.php`

```
$html='SOME HTML';
include("../../dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('FileName.pdf');        
//header('location:Other.php);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to question

For this to work you would need to move the second `header` call into the `PDFRecipt` file. At the moment with both of them in the one file your second call to `header` is overriding the first.

Remember that headers are sent when the output is sent to the users browser, which is why you often see people calling `exit()` right after a `header('Location: http://example.org');`.

So any subsequent calls to set the same header, in this case `Location`, will override the first until the headers are sent.

It is also worth pointing out that you should be using full web URLs in `Location`:

> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including
>   the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept
>   relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
>   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a
>   relative one yourself

according to the `header` page in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

#### Update from comments

So you are using the `stream()` method to send the client the PDF - you cannot combine this with a `Location:` header. This is because DOMPDF has already flushed content to screen. I had assumed that your `PDFRecipt.php` file was storing the PDF to disk somewhere.

See DOMPDF source code for more details: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/source/browse/trunk/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php#3061

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. It creates the PDF file but does not redirect. :(

Comment: What does your `PDFRecipt.php` file contain? Please update your question with the source code. I have never had an issue implementing the above - perhaps there is an error or a conflict in the code causing it not to redirect.